# angularjs - loading images issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image

I have a small issue how to handle loading an images so the browser not try to load a images it cant find because angularjs havent kicked in yet.
How can i do that?, with some ng-if? or ng-hide/show?, but then it still find the images tag before angularjs kicked in.

If you can help me how to handle this issue too:
i need to have a standard image all the time, but if there is a campaign on my site, i need to "overwrite" that image with some data i got from a http call

```
STANDARD IMAGE
<img class="img-responsive hidden-sm hidden-xs" src="/images/header.jpg">            
<img class="img-responsive hidden-lg hidden-md" src="/images/header-mobile.jpg">

CAMPAIGN IMAGE
<img class="img-responsive hidden-sm hidden-xs" src="/images/{{campaign}}.jpg">            
<img class="img-responsive hidden-lg hidden-md" src="/images/{{campaign}}-mobile.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc). Within this attribute, you can use the `{{campaign}}` markup.

In your case it should work with:

```
<img class="img-responsive hidden-lg hidden-md" ng-src="/images/{{campaign}}-mobile.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use angualar expressions in `src` tag, because browser will try to fetch it literally, without evaluating angular expression.

You have to use ng-src directive.

here You can get more info: [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

example:

```
STANDARD IMAGE
<img class="img-responsive hidden-sm hidden-xs" src="/images/header.jpg">            
<img class="img-responsive hidden-lg hidden-md" src="/images/header-mobile.jpg">

CAMPAIGN IMAGE
<img class="img-responsive hidden-sm hidden-xs" ng-src="/images/{{campaign}}.jpg">            
<img class="img-responsive hidden-lg hidden-md" ng-src="/images/{{campaign}}-mobile.jpg">
```

Answer (score -1):

you can set the stranded image in the controller

```
$scope.campaign = "defaultImage.jpeg";
```

then you can use directive [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

you can use that in here as below,

```
<img class="img-responsive hidden-sm hidden-xs" ng-src="/images/{{campaign}}.jpg">
```

`src` will get only if `$scope.campaign` is present.